# Как найти символ или пару символов в тексте (JAVA)?

Tags: java, android

Есть прочитанный из файла текст в переменной типа String all_text.

В нем есть разделы помеченные вот так:

```
[f1] Текст какой-то.... [g5] Текст другой.....
```

Как осуществить поиск по тексту и сохранить (в переменную String part_txt) строки находящиеся между `[f1]` и `[g5]`?

Comment: Что именно вызывает затруднения? Найти индекс подстроки в строке? Скопировать подстроку из строки?

Comment: Скопировать в переменную path_txt текст между [f1] и [g5]. Соответственно уметь находить в тексте метки типа [f1] и [g5].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String ReturnStr(String m1, String m2, String text, int startIndex)
    {
       int first, second; 
       //не работаем с пустыми строками
       if(m1.length() == 0 || m2.length() == 0 || text.length() == 0) return null;       
       //проверим, не выходит ли стартовый индекс за пределы текста
       if( startIndex < 0 || startIndex > text.length()) return null;       
       //находим первую метку и сдвигаем индекс на длину метки
       first = text.indexOf(m1,startIndex);
       //если начальной метки не нашлось, возвращаем null
       //но можно изменить 2 строки ниже и вести отсчет с начала текста, это по желанию
       if(first < 0)return null;// заменить эту строку
       first += m1.length();//     и эту на if(first < 0) first = 0;       
       //проверим, не является ли метка концом текста
       if(first >= text.length()) return null;       
       //находим вторую метку
       second = text.indexOf(m2, first);
       //если нашли только начальную метку, вырезать весь текст до конца
       if(second < 0)return text.substring(first);
       return text.substring(first, second);
    }
```

Поиск по любым заданным меткам. А вообще - тут много чего можно улучшить, зависит от решаемой задачи.

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте так:

```
String text = "[f1] Текст какой-то.... [g5] [f1] Текст другой..... [g5]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[f1\\](.+?)\\[g5\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(1));
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Вывод:

```
Текст какой-то.... 
Текст другой.....
```

Если необходимо, пробежаться по всему тексту, это очевидно, цикл -> проверка на совпадение.

Comment: Отлично! Все получилось. Спасибо.